# Safari won't play HTML5 video

Tags: html, safari, html5-video

I'm trying to create a HTML5 video background for a website but I cannot seem to get it to work on Safari. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here's the HTML video tags I'm using

```
<video id="bgVideo" class="bg__video" autoplay loop>
  <source src="./vid/Sample_Vid.ogv" type="video/ogv">
  <source src="./vid/Sample_Vid.m4v" type="video/m4v">
  <source src="./vid/Sample_Vid.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

I've tried adding a script tag under it to start playing the video with JS but that's not helped either.

```
document.getElementById("bgVideo").play();
```

When I inspect the page it looks like the video element is taking up space in the DOM but it's just invisible basically.

I've also tried opening the .m4v files directly in the browser & it plays it there so I assume the file isn't an issue. These were all generated from [easyhtml5video.com](http://easyhtml5video.com)

I also have the Modernizer script to detect if autoplay is enabled for the browser which I've had to alter based on a [pull request in the github repo](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/pull/1795) as it was always saying that Safari doesn't support autoplay otherwise.

The test site I've setup is http://treetopia.neilnand.co.uk/

Answer (score 4):

The supported video format for Safari is `mp4` with [`H.264`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC) encoding. (you have a `.m4v` extension and file type)

Comment: Thanks, that just made me think & notice the problem. Safari does play .m4v files but I'd set the type to video/m4v, it should have been video/mp4 which I've just changed & it now works.

Answer (score 0):

If video does not has sound - use

```
document.getElementById("bgVideo").volume = 0;
```

Safari don't allow autoplay for videos with sound.

Comment: Or use the `muted` attribute for the `<video>`, which seems to do the same and also works.